# Python openCV: I get an unchanged image when I use cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image as a numpy array with the shape (480,640) in grayscale.

I want to lay a colored mask over the image and need to get the image in the same shape to do it, which is (480,640,3).

Here is what I tried:

```
print str(img.shape) +' '+ str(type(img)) +' '+ str(img.dtype)
# prints: (480, 640) <type 'numpy.ndarray'> uint8

cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR, img, 3)
# this line seems to have no effect although I set it to 3 channels

print str(img.shape) +' '+ str(type(img)) +' '+ str(img.dtype)
# prints: (480, 640) <type 'numpy.ndarray'> uint8

rowCounter = 0
while rowCounter < img.shape[0]:
    columnCounter = 0
    while columnCounter < img.shape[1]:
        if img[rowCounter, columnCounter] == 0:
            img[rowCounter, columnCounter] = [0, 0, 0]
        else:
            img[rowCounter, columnCounter] = [255, 255, 255]
        columnCounter += 1
    rowCounter += 1
```

Ok, the code stops on the line where I want to assign the three values ([0, 0, 0]) instead of the single value (0). The error message reads as follows:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I change from single value to three values? Is there a function I am not finding?

Thank you!

Comment: you also can skip the while loops: `img_color[img_gray==0]=(255,255,255)`

Comment: @berak: This is not working for the same reason in this case I guess.

Comment: apply the answer below, then try again ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is that you need to assign the converted image to a new name.

I'm not sure if using the c++ format of providing the target image as an argument works. I would just do it the usual python (cv2) way of assigning to a name (same name is fine).

Also, you don't need to assign the number of channels. The conversion type takes care of that.

```
#            cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR, img, 3)
color_mask = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Does that get you the image you want?

By the way, as long as you are using numpy/opencv you probably want to look into ways of making it more efficient. If you do individual pixel access across a whole image/numpy array, that's a red flag (for opencv in python).

Below is code that shows the conversion but then ignores that and shows (as I understand it) how to apply a more efficient mask.

## Copy-Paste Working (and More Efficient) Example

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# setup an original image (this will work for anyone without needing to load one)
shape = (480, 640)
img_gray = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=np.uint8)
img_gray.fill(127)
img_gray[0:40, 100:140] = 0  # some "off" values
cv2.imshow('original grayscale image', img_gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)  # press any key to continue

# convert the gray image to color (not used. just to demonstrate)
img_color = cv2.cvtColor(img_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imshow('color converted grayscale image (not used. just to show how to use cvtColor)', img_color)
cv2.waitKey(0)  # press any key to continue

# a simplified version of what your code did to apply a mask
# make a white image.
# and then set it to black wherever the original grayscale image is 0
img_color = np.ndarray(img_gray.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint8)
img_color.fill(255)
cv2.imshow('base color image', img_color)
cv2.waitKey(0)  # press any key to continue

# this is not the fastest way, but I think it's more logical until you need more speed
# the fastest way specifically to black out parts of the image would
# be np.bitwise_and(...)
black_points = np.where(img_gray == 0)
print('found {} points to mask'.format(len(black_points[0])))
img_color[black_points] = (0, 0, 0)

# a more efficient and still straightforward method you could use:
img_color[img_gray==0] = (0, 0, 0)
cv2.imshow('masked color image', img_color)
cv2.waitKey(0)  # press any key to continue

# clean up explicitly
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: That's working. I used the opencv documentation and thought that setting the destination file would do the trick and the return of the function is maybe only a boolean or so. I should have checked. Thank you! :)

Comment: @cowhi That's good to hear. Thanks for letting everyone know it worked. The second part of your code is not the main question, but I thought you might like to see a more efficient way to do it. I updated the answer to show how you might be able to do the mask.

Comment: Wow, thanks again. I actually generate a second image as a mask and then use cv2.add() to get the mask and the image together. That works fine so far.